# Jersey REST WS - request body UTF-8

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have simple Jersey REST webServices:

```
@POST
@Path("/label")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)      
public Response setLabels(String requestBody) { 
    System.out.println(requestBody);
......
}
```

Request passes some text with "special" non-English characters

```
 [{"За обекта"}]
```

I can see in Firebug that request passed with correct UTF-8 content and charset

```
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

Though on on server output does not present desirable charset:

```
  [{"?? ??????"}]
```

Any Idea what and were went wrong? How can I capture text in correct charset on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`. It uses the platform default encoding, which is typically not UTF-8. So you are getting the correct data in, it's just getting mangled when you print it to the console.

I had the exact same problem a few weeks ago - drove me nuts until I figured it out. What made it worse is that I actually *had* an encoding-related bug in another part of the code.

Comment: Indeed values passed correctly through REST, so it was only representation issue.